# simple if/else in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, conditional-statements

I display the form validation error in codeigniter as below:

```
<?php echo form_error('name', '<div class="form_error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

i want to do it so that if there is error, then it should print error, otherwise it should print the info div.

For example,

```
if form_error, then 

<?php echo form_error('name', '<div class="form_error">', '</div>'); ?>

else
<div class="info">Your first and last name. </div>
```

As form_error is not just a simple variable that i can check if it is empty then print info. How can i do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if ( form_error('name') )
{
  echo form_error('name');
}
```

For form_error might not be a variable but it's a function that returns a string.  If the string is empty (NULL, FALSE, "", 0, ...), the if statement will fail (meaning there is no error) and the form_error('name') won't be called.

Answer (score 2):

This sould do it :

```
if (form_error('name')){

     echo form_error('name', '<div class="form_error">', '</div>');

} else {

    echo '<div class="info">Your first and last name. </div>';

}
```